# regex - bad string due to invalid escape char?

Tags: json, regex

I recently inherited some code with a regex expression that's part of a JSON k/v pair that I believe checks for the string "ERROR" in a log file between 10am to 7pm and excluding both 4pm to 4:29 and 4:40 to 5pm

```
[ 
  { 
    "log": "/working/dir/${instance}/log/log.log",
    "alerts": [
      {
        "severity": "critical",
        "string": "(1([0-5,7-9]:|6:(?!3))||[0,2]\d:)\d\d:\d\d.*?ERROR"
       }
     ]
   }
]
```

However, when try to validate this JSON, I get a "bad string" error due to an invalid escape.

Here's the error message from the JSON validator:

```
Error: Parse error on line 7:
...
    "string": "(1([0-5,7-9]:|6:(?!
  ----------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

I am not quite sure what could be wrong here.  If someone could assist, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The `||` is suspicious and looks like a human error. Unless this whole first 
 group  is optional. Also, the commas should be removed.

Comment: The error message looks like you have an unpaired parenthesis somewhere earlier in your JSON, though.

Comment: `\d` isn't a valid escape in JSON, change them to `\\d`.

Comment: This worked!  Thank you!